# How to read stackoverflow rss feed using linq to xml 

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-xml

I am trying read rss feed of stack overflow using Linq to xml. I am unable to get the entry nodes, as it is returning empty list. This I've tried so far, can any one point out what i am doing wrong here?

Here I am binding to the grid view:

```
private void StackoverflowFeedList()
{
    grdFeedView.DataSource = StackoverflowUtils.GetStackOverflowFeeds();
    grdFeedView.DataBind();
}
```

This is the method which will get all feeds:

```
public static IEnumerable<StackOverflowFeedItems> GetStackOverflowFeeds ()
{
    XNamespace Snmp = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
    XDocument RssFeed = XDocument.Load(@"http://stackoverflow.com/feeds");
    var posts = from item in RssFeed.Descendants("entry")
                select new StackOverflowFeedItems
                {
                   QuestionID = item.Element(Snmp +"id").Value,
                   QuestionTitle = item.Element(Snmp +"title").Value,
                   AuthorName = item.Element(Snmp +"name").Value,
                   CategoryTag = (from category in item.Elements(Snmp +"category")
                                  orderby category
                                  select category.Value).ToList(),
                   CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse(item.Element(Snmp +"published").Value),
                   QuestionSummary = item.Element(Snmp +"summary").Value
                };
    return posts.ToList();
}
```

And this is the class I am using for binding:

```
public class StackOverflowFeedItems
{
    public string   QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string   QuestionTitle { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> CategoryTag { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set;  }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string QuestionSummary { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why you don't want to use "classic" approach with SyndicationFeed Class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using the namespace variable you've declared. Try using

```
RssFeed.Descendants(Snmp + "entry")
```

(And likewise for *all* other places where you're referring to particular names.)

I'm not saying that's necessarily *all* of what you need to fix, but it's the most obvious problem. You should also consider using the explicit conversions of `XElement` and `XAttribute` instead of the `Value` property, e.g.

```
CreatedDate = (DateTime) item.Element(Snmp +"published")
```

I'd also encourage you to pay more attention to indentation, and use pascalCase consistently when naming local variables. (Quite why the namespace variable is called `Snmp` is another oddity... cut and paste?)

Comment: i added that Snmp, but it is not returning any thing. empty results, check my edited question

Comment: @Ravi: You're still not doing it on the first call: `RssFeed.Descendants("entry")`.

Comment: i am getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object.