# Orchard CMS EntryPointNotFound Exception in Rss Feeds

Tags: rss, orchardcms

If I navigate directly to an Orchard blog post feed (Orchard 1.5.1)

http://riders-test.apphb.com/rss?containerid=86   (blog can be found at [/news-blog/blog](http://riders-test.apphb.com/news-blog/blog))

I get the "Opps. Something went wrong ... sorry" Page

Looking at the logs I see this exception.

```
2013-01-24 11:19:52,805 [27] Orchard.Exceptions.DefaultExceptionPolicy - An unexpected exception was caught
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.
   at System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider.GetValue(String key)
   at Contrib.Taxonomies.StandardQueries.TermFeedQuery.Match(FeedContext context) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard.AppHarbor\Orchard.AppHarbor.Web\Modules\Contrib.Taxonomies\StandardQueries\TermFeedQuery.cs:line 29
   at Orchard.Core.Feeds.Controllers.FeedController.<>c__DisplayClassb.<Index>b__3(IFeedQueryProvider provider) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Feeds\Controllers\FeedController.cs:line 40
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Orchard.Core.Feeds.Controllers.FeedController.Index(String format) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Feeds\Controllers\FeedController.cs:line 39
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
2013-01-24 11:19:54,092 [27] Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.Coordinators.ContentPartDriverCoordinator - ArgumentNullException thrown from IContentPartDriver by Orchard.Core.Navigation.Drivers.MenuWidgetPartDriver
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Where[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Orchard.Core.Navigation.Drivers.MenuWidgetPartDriver.<>c__DisplayClass9.<Display>b__7() in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Navigation\Drivers\MenuWidgetPartDriver.cs:line 122
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentPartDriver`1.<>c__DisplayClassf.<ContentShape>b__e(BuildShapeContext ctx) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentPartDriver.cs:line 129
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentPartDriver`1.<>c__DisplayClass15.<ContentShapeImplementation>b__14(BuildShapeContext ctx) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentPartDriver.cs:line 138
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentShapeResult.ApplyImplementation(BuildShapeContext context, String displayType) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentShapeResult.cs:line 39
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentShapeResult.Apply(BuildDisplayContext context) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentShapeResult.cs:line 21
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.Coordinators.ContentPartDriverCoordinator.<>c__DisplayClassa.<BuildDisplay>b__9(IContentPartDriver driver) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\Coordinators\ContentPartDriverCoordinator.cs:line 49
   at Orchard.InvokeExtensions.Invoke[TEvents](IEnumerable`1 events, Action`1 dispatch, ILogger logger) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\InvokeExtensions.cs:line 17
2013-01-24 11:19:54,189 [27] Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.Coordinators.ContentPartDriverCoordinator - NullReferenceException thrown from IContentPartDriver by Orchard.Core.Navigation.Drivers.MenuWidgetPartDriver
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Orchard.Core.Navigation.Drivers.MenuWidgetPartDriver.<>c__DisplayClass9.<Display>b__7() in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Navigation\Drivers\MenuWidgetPartDriver.cs:line 84
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentPartDriver`1.<>c__DisplayClassf.<ContentShape>b__e(BuildShapeContext ctx) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentPartDriver.cs:line 129
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentPartDriver`1.<>c__DisplayClass15.<ContentShapeImplementation>b__14(BuildShapeContext ctx) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentPartDriver.cs:line 138
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentShapeResult.ApplyImplementation(BuildShapeContext context, String displayType) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentShapeResult.cs:line 39
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentShapeResult.Apply(BuildDisplayContext context) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentShapeResult.cs:line 21
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.Coordinators.ContentPartDriverCoordinator.<>c__DisplayClassa.<BuildDisplay>b__9(IContentPartDriver driver) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\Coordinators\ContentPartDriverCoordinator.cs:line 49
   at Orchard.InvokeExtensions.Invoke[TEvents](IEnumerable`1 events, Action`1 dispatch, ILogger logger) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\InvokeExtensions.cs:line 17
2013-01-24 11:20:00,911 [29] Orchard.Exceptions.DefaultExceptionPolicy - An unexpected exception was caught
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.
   at System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider.GetValue(String key)
   at Contrib.Taxonomies.StandardQueries.TermFeedQuery.Match(FeedContext context) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard.AppHarbor\Orchard.AppHarbor.Web\Modules\Contrib.Taxonomies\StandardQueries\TermFeedQuery.cs:line 29
   at Orchard.Core.Feeds.Controllers.FeedController.<>c__DisplayClassb.<Index>b__3(IFeedQueryProvider provider) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Feeds\Controllers\FeedController.cs:line 40
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Orchard.Core.Feeds.Controllers.FeedController.Index(String format) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Feeds\Controllers\FeedController.cs:line 39
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
2013-01-24 11:20:01,712 [29] Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.Coordinators.ContentPartDriverCoordinator - ArgumentNullException thrown from IContentPartDriver by Orchard.Core.Navigation.Drivers.MenuWidgetPartDriver
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Where[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Orchard.Core.Navigation.Drivers.MenuWidgetPartDriver.<>c__DisplayClass9.<Display>b__7() in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Navigation\Drivers\MenuWidgetPartDriver.cs:line 122
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentPartDriver`1.<>c__DisplayClassf.<ContentShape>b__e(BuildShapeContext ctx) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentPartDriver.cs:line 129
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentPartDriver`1.<>c__DisplayClass15.<ContentShapeImplementation>b__14(BuildShapeContext ctx) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentPartDriver.cs:line 138
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentShapeResult.ApplyImplementation(BuildShapeContext context, String displayType) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentShapeResult.cs:line 39
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentShapeResult.Apply(BuildDisplayContext context) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentShapeResult.cs:line 21
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.Coordinators.ContentPartDriverCoordinator.<>c__DisplayClassa.<BuildDisplay>b__9(IContentPartDriver driver) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\Coordinators\ContentPartDriverCoordinator.cs:line 49
   at Orchard.InvokeExtensions.Invoke[TEvents](IEnumerable`1 events, Action`1 dispatch, ILogger logger) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\InvokeExtensions.cs:line 17
2013-01-24 11:20:01,815 [29] Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.Coordinators.ContentPartDriverCoordinator - NullReferenceException thrown from IContentPartDriver by Orchard.Core.Navigation.Drivers.MenuWidgetPartDriver
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Orchard.Core.Navigation.Drivers.MenuWidgetPartDriver.<>c__DisplayClass9.<Display>b__7() in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Navigation\Drivers\MenuWidgetPartDriver.cs:line 84
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentPartDriver`1.<>c__DisplayClassf.<ContentShape>b__e(BuildShapeContext ctx) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentPartDriver.cs:line 129
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentPartDriver`1.<>c__DisplayClass15.<ContentShapeImplementation>b__14(BuildShapeContext ctx) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentPartDriver.cs:line 138
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentShapeResult.ApplyImplementation(BuildShapeContext context, String displayType) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentShapeResult.cs:line 39
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentShapeResult.Apply(BuildDisplayContext context) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentShapeResult.cs:line 21
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.Coordinators.ContentPartDriverCoordinator.<>c__DisplayClassa.<BuildDisplay>b__9(IContentPartDriver driver) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\Coordinators\ContentPartDriverCoordinator.cs:line 49
   at Orchard.InvokeExtensions.Invoke[TEvents](IEnumerable`1 events, Action`1 dispatch, ILogger logger) in C:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard\InvokeExtensions.cs:line 17
```

Short of starting again with a default orchard install (Time wise not an option) I'm really not sure how to fix this.

Please help.

Comment: I cannot reach either your blog page or rss feed. 404. Are you sure 86 is the id of the blog itself? Is it published? ^^

Comment: Yes, sorry its news-blog/blog http://riders-test.apphb.com/news-blog/blog

Comment: Maybe the time might better be spent trying to upgrade to a newer version, which might actually solve this issue and many more you haven't yet noticed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read stackoverflow rss feed using linq to xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031652/how-to-read-stackoverflow-rss-feed-using-linq-to-xml)